# Как я могу поменять начало недели на Plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, plotly

Как я могу поменять начало недели на Plotly.js? Столкнулся с проблемой, что отображаются только воскресенья на xaxis, мне нужно чтобы отображались понедельники.

```
xaxis: {
    type: 'date',
    automargin: true,
    tickformat: '%d.%m',
    maxPadding: 1,
},
yaxis: {
    tickmode: 'array',
    automargin: true,
    showticklabels: false,
    showgrid: false,
},
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908032/show-full-axis-range-for-plotly-chart

Comment: к сожалению свойство range разрушает мне весь мой график, есть ли какие то другие способы?autorange: false,
range: [0, 7],